# How to do t-test with multiple probabilities?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have given some distribution among candy preferences. 30% of people like candy1, 30% of people like candy2, and 40% of people like candy3. The total amount of people is known, e.g. 100.
Now the candy manufacturer says that all his candy flavors are being liked equally. This hypothesis shall be tested with a significance of 5%. I never did such a test with multiple probabilities.

My idea is to compare the mean value with the expected mean value (where 100/3 people would like each candy flavor equally). But I am not sure how to calculate the actual mean value.

Comment: But I dont have multiple samples, I have only one. And I'm also not given any standard deviations. Only the values I mentioned above.

Comment: The "classical" answer here is a chi squared test for goodness of fit of a categorical distribution. Namely, you assume that $\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{(n_i-np_i)^2}{np_i}$ is chi squared distributed with 3-1=2 degrees of freedom and accept or reject the null based on that, where $n_i$ are observed frequencies, $p_i$ are predicted probabilities, and $n$ is the total number of observations. The critical value at 0.05 significance level for this distribution is a little bit below 6. Apparently there is a different (non-equivalent) approach, called a G-test, that is popular nowadays.

Comment: By the way, this chi square method as well as the G-test are approximate, because the test statistic is not exactly $\chi^2(2)$ distributed. There are exact methods out there, such as the multinomial test and Fisher's . But they get computationally expensive with large enough samples, especially if there are too many bins. Your case is small enough that software can handle an exact test, and is apparently small enough that it would be recommended to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment** following @Ian's first Comment. This is not
a formal answer to your Question, but thinking about
what I have shown may get you started in a useful
direction. [I am not talking about Ian's G test. And a t test is not what you want.]

If the information at the start of your Question is
correct, then preferences of $n = 100$ people might be
as in the vector `x` below, which I simulated in R.

```
set.seed(128)
x = sample(1:3, 100, rep=T, p = c(.3,.3,.4))
table(x)
x
 1  2  3 
33 28 39
```

How would you use a chi-squared test to see if these counts are consistent with the manufacturer's null hypothesis that all three flavors are 'liked equally'?

Results from R, are as follows. How is the chi-squared statistic computed in `chisq.test`? (Can you find it using a calculator?) How is the P-value found? Is the null hypothesis rejected? Do you think $n = 100$ subjects is
enough to investigate whether the null hypothesis is true?

```
chisq.test(c(33, 28, 39)) 

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  c(33, 28, 39)
X-squared = 1.82, df = 2, p-value = 0.4025
```

*Note:* If no other probabilities are provided
for `chisq.test`, the `given probabilities` are assumed to be
all equal: here $(1/3, 1/3, 1/3).$